# select last 25 records from SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to retrain last 25 entered records and delete remaining records according to id.

```
DELETE * FROM list 
WHERE id NOT IN 
( 
    SELECT * 
    FROM ( 
        SELECT * 
        FROM 'list' 
        ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 25 
    ) as rows 
)
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: mysql database system i am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE * 
FROM 'list' 
WHERE id NOT IN ( SELECT id 
                  FROM 'list' 
                  ORDER BY id DESC 
                  LIMIT 25 )
```

Comment: Not getting the meaning of your last message. Can you please re-phrase?

Answer (score 0):

Deleting while selecting from the same table isn't permitted in MySQL.

You can try something like this:

```
 SELECT @rows_to_delete:=COUNT(*)-25 FROM list;
 DELETE FROM list ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 0, @rows_to_delete;
```

**NB: this is not tested please test before running it on real data.**

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is close, but what you need to change is just to filter for id in your subquery, don't select everything, because that doesn't make sense. You want to see if a single item (id) is not in a group of things (all columns).

Try changing your query to this:

```
DELETE FROM list
WHERE id NOT IN(
  SELECT id
  FROM list
  ORDER BY id DESC
  LIMIT 25);
```

I would test this with some dummy data first, but I believe it will do what you want.